# Hide a DIV [Rails]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hiding a DIV would be easy enough in Javascript, but is there some Rails-y way to do it? I can think of some ways to do it by calling Javascript from a partial (.erb), of course, but I'd prefer not to write any Javascript at all. Possible?

**Edit:** The page is loaded and I would like to hide the DIV **after** (well, on) an Ajax call, so I'm in one of those `render :update` blocks.

Comment: how/when do you want it hidden? On load, after an event, or after an ajax call?

Comment: thanks Luca. Why is it bad? Please elaborate so I can know if you have a point or are just ranting.

Comment: @Daniel: http://www.robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: Thanks Luca, interesting. I think most of those concerns don't apply to Rails produced Javascript. The idea is that 99% of the time, you're doing standard stuff with standard libs (prototype and Scriptaliciousousu sorry about the spelling it's 5am)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or, right in your view:

For a class-specified div:

```
<%= link_to_function "Toggle", "$('.some_div').toggle()" %>
```

For an ID-specified div:

```
<%= link_to_function "Toggle", "$('#some_div').toggle()" %>
```

(notice the hash-mark)

Added period to class specific div and hash to id specific div

Comment: Yep, pure JS. Hiding a div is definitely JS's domain; passing back and forth to the server to hide a div is overkill.

Comment: `link_to_function` has been removed in Rails 4.0.2.

Answer (score 6):

```
render :update do |page|
    page.hide 'div_id'
end
```

You can throw this in you respond_to block or an RJS template.

Another helpful tip, using the same syntax:

```
render :update do |page|
    page << 'arbitrary javascript code goes here.'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To render an RJS update from your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render(:update) { |page| page.hide('element_id') } }
end
```

You can look up the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M001638) for other RJS responses.

Comment: Awesome, great response. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know rails, but can you just output something like style="display:none;" into the div tag?

Comment: I don't know rails either :), but my feeling is that I cannot... I can only touch stuff that is within a DIV or other ID addressable piece of the HTML page.

Comment: bummer :( - guess I'd probably get jquery from the toolbox at that point then.

Comment: Nah, it has prototype and scriptalicious (sp.) by default, but even with plain JS it's easy. But now with the responses here (above) I'm set to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to_function "Toggle", visual_effect(:toggle_blind, "some_div") %>
```