# MouseOver toggle a div in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, html, toggle, show-hide

I have an index page of `Tasks` which I generated from a scaffold.

In order to make it a little more visually appealing, I'd like to hide the edit view and delete links unless there is a **mouseover** event on the title.

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %> - <%= link_to 'Move onto '+task.name+' and start its clock', task_start_path(task) %></td>
    <td>/ <%= link_to 'Rename task', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td>/ <%= link_to 'Check its clocks', task %></td>
    <td>/ <%= link_to 'Destroy task', task, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is there a clean way to do this in the `index.html.erb` file or do I need to call some custom helper javascript functions?

I found [Hide a DIV [Rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543760/hide-a-div-rails) but it toggles on click rather than on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) in rails 3.  You can put a special class on the  and on the  elements that you want to hide (or on the links themselves).

Something like:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr class="hide_on_hover">
    <td><%= task.name %> - <%= link_to 'Move onto '+task.name+' and start its clock', task_start_path(task) %></td>
    <td class="hideable">/ <%= link_to 'Rename task', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td>/ <%= link_to 'Check its clocks', task %></td>
    <td class="hideable">/ <%= link_to 'Destroy task', task, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and then in your application.js file you would add javascript to fire on document load, find those elements and add the hover actions. If you're using JQuery (recommended) you can see an easy way to do that (with examples) here:
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Still haven't gotten a chance to try this, but I'll mark as answer.